# Several SharePoint Job Timers Updating the same SPList

Tags: c#, sharepoint, timer, jobs, splist

I have a Timer job set to run every minute to update SPList data.
In my log, I have frequent logs saying that the list is being updated by another entity. that I have to refresh my browser, etc. 
What should I do to get this job run correctly?

Comment: It seems the timer job is running longer than 1 minute. This will cause this issue. What happens if you decrease it to e.g. 5 minutes?

Comment: I don't know yet what heppens.But isn't there any other solution to keep it run every minute?

Comment: I've been thinking, if the timer job runs longer than a minute, it will not start again.
So, there is another issue with your code. If you e.g. retrieve an SPListItem and update SPList properties, you'll get an error if you update SPListItem afterwards.
So, you'll need to debug your code for such issues.

Comment: I agree this might not be the job's issue. Now I have to find out what other part of the code is trying to update the same data. Not easy knowing that I am not the one who coded that (the code is 2 years old!)

Comment: It does not have to be the same data. It might be related data, e.g. updating SPList and then SPListItem in that list will cause the same error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will let you know if I fix the bug.